# Combining check all that apply race/ethnicity variables into one category in R

Tags: r

Below is an example of the structure of my dataset with white, asian, black and other as binary variables. I would like to create a new variable called "race_category" where if someone selected more than 1 race category, they would be assigned with "more than 1," if else, then they would be assigned the race they selected.

```
white <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)
asian <- c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0)
black <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0)
other <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)

dat <- data.frame(white,asian,black,other)
dat
```

This is an example of what I would like as my output:

```
race_cat <- c("black","more than 1","more than 1","more than 1","other","asian","asian","white","black","white")

dat <- data.frame(white,asian,black,other,race_cat)

dat
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I am quite new to R and have no idea how to approach this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max.col` to select the column with the "1" unless there are multiple "1"s.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    race_cat = ifelse(
      rowSums(.) > 1, "multiple", names(dat)[max.col(.)]))

   white asian black other race_cat
1      0     0     1     0    black
2      1     0     1     0 multiple
3      1     0     1     0 multiple
4      1     1     1     0 multiple
5      0     0     0     1    other
6      0     1     0     0    asian
7      0     1     0     0    asian
8      1     0     0     0    white
9      0     0     1     0    black
10     1     0     0     0    white
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::case_when` you can set your conditions to create the required variable

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(race_cat = rowSums(.),
         race_cat = case_when(race_cat == 1 & white == 1 ~ "white",
                         race_cat == 1 & asian == 1 ~ "asian",
                         race_cat == 1 & black == 1 ~ "black",
                         race_cat == 1 & other == 1 ~ "other",
                         TRUE ~ "more than 1"))
#>    white asian black other          race_cat
#> 1      0     0     1     0        black
#> 2      1     0     1     0  more than 1
#> 3      1     0     1     0  more than 1
#> 4      1     1     1     0  more than 1
#> 5      0     0     0     1        other
#> 6      0     1     0     0        asian
#> 7      0     1     0     0        asian
#> 8      1     0     0     0        white
#> 9      0     0     1     0        black
#> 10     1     0     0     0        white
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use base R's [`apply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) for this:

```
dat$race_cat <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) {ifelse(sum(x) > 1, "more than 1", names(x[x != 0]))})
```

You apply a function over rows:

1. check if the sum is greater than 1, then it's `"more than 1"`
2. if the sum is not greater than 1, then it's the name of the column with non zero value.

Result:

```
#>    white asian black other    race_cat
#> 1      0     0     1     0       black
#> 2      1     0     1     0 more than 1
#> 3      1     0     1     0 more than 1
#> 4      1     1     1     0 more than 1
#> 5      0     0     0     1       other
#> 6      0     1     0     0       asian
#> 7      0     1     0     0       asian
#> 8      1     0     0     0       white
#> 9      0     0     1     0       black
#> 10     1     0     0     0       white
```

(Note that this solution works well if you have only zeros and ones in your data as it sums the row - otherwise you would have to use another condition to check that. If you have some row with only zeros, this code will return [`NA`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html) for that row.)

#### Data

```
dat <-structure(list(white = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), asian = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), black = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), other = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```